# Can't use any Fontawesome icon with "-o" ending

Tags: html, css, icons, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

For a website I want to use icons from fontawesome. For example I need to use the heart icon:

***works:***

```
<i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

The icon is available as filled version or only the outline, and I only need the "outline" version of the icon. To get the outline version you just change the corresponding CSS class by adding "-o" like this:

***doesn't work:***

```
<i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

But the "-o" version just is not displayed. There are many icons declared on the fontawesome website where one can add "-o" to show only the outline. But none of them is displayed on when I try it. The normal icons work. **I also did a search for a "-o" declaration in all downloaded CSS files but didn't find anything! Like they didn't implement it..**

I can't find the problem. Seems to me like they "forgot" to implement the "-o" versions in the latest Fontawesome 5.0.4 file.

PS: I added the icons to my project by downloading the CSS file "fontawesome-all.min.css". Use [this link](http://fontawesome.io/icons/) to search for icons, e.g. "heart".

*Like requested, my whole code:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/css/fontawesome-all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h6 class="card-title">Some Title</h6>

                    <!-- Stats -->
                    <p class="card-text font-weight-light">
                        <span class="mr-4"><i class="fa fa-comment" aria-hidden="true"></i>0</span>
                        <span class="mr-4"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>0</span>
                        <span><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>0</span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>   
        </div>        
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The only possible explanation is that your font awesome file is outdated. Are you sure it is the right one ?

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your code, of where this is happening?

Comment: @trichetriche Yes I downloaded the newest version 5.0.4.

Comment: @MykolaSenechyn The example above is the exact code I use on my website.

Comment: I think he meant your whole code, such as how you import the fonts

Comment: Could it be a cache issue ?  try reset your cache, on chrome it's ctrl+shift+r

Comment: @MykolaSenechyn No, same result. But the real question is why a search for "<iconname-o" on all downloaded CSS files returns nothing! I think they like "forgot" to implement/ship the latest final version correctly..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[TL;DR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TL;DR)

use:
`<i class="far fa-heart" aria-hidden></i>`

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.9.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Regular/outline (-o) -->
<i class="far fa-heart" aria-hidden></I>

<!-- Solid/filled -->
<i class="fas fa-heart" aria-hidden></i>
```

---

**Explanation:**

Since Font Awesome Version 5 severall things changed.

Changes (not all):

- `fa` has changed to `far` (font awesome regular)
- all `-o` icons have been integrated in the regular style and left of the -o

Here is the [upgrade guide from v4 to v5](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/upgrading-from-4)

Website:

- The old website http://fontawesome.io/ is for Version 4.X (UPDATE: redirects now to .com)
- **Version 5** you can find at https://fontawesome.com
- Search for icons here: https://fontawesome.com/icons

Comment: Thank you! It all works now. I wondered why there are multiple "official" websites.. And both seemed up-to-date, but fontawesome.com is the latest.

Comment: They have changed it, now the https://fontawesome.io website redirects to the https://fontawesome.com one

Answer (score 2):

**Is this what you wanter?**

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<i class="fa fa-heart-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Comment: Thank you, the CDN version seems to work but you use Fontawesome version 4.7.0. It would we nice to know why it doesn't work with the newest version 5.0.4. But if nobody brings a solution for the newest version I will accept yours.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using font awesome version 5, specify the style of the icon between **regular**: *far fa-heart*, **solid**: *fas fa-heart* and **light**: *fal fa-heart*. If you use *fa fa-heart*, by default the solid version will be used.

Put the mouseover this link to view various icon styles: https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&q=heart

In v5, there is no *fa fa-heart-o*. It was for v4. Otherwise use a CDN of v4.

Answer (score 0):

Use class="far fa-heart" for regular heart (outline), class="fas fa-heart" for solid heart