# Why fa-heart-o not working in Fontawesome 5?

Tags: html, css, icons, font-awesome

I want to use `fa-heart-o` in Fontawesome 5 free version but it is not working. what should I do? can I use 2 version of Fontawesome in a page? 4.7 and 5.1? because it is working in 4.7 version.

this is my code:

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <li>
            <i class="fas fa-heart-o"></i>
        </li>
        <script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Comment: Please show enough code so we can see the problem for ourselves. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @AHaworth I added an example code

Comment: Fontawesome 5 changed a few things, including no longer adding the -o for an outline only icon. This SO question has the answer you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48301739/cant-use-any-fontawesome-icon-with-o-ending

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <li>
            <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i>
        </li>
        <script src='https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js' crossorigin='anonymous'></script>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change to `<i class="fas fa-heart-o"></i>` to `<i class="fas fa-heart"></i>`
because with the `-o` in awesome font 5 it wont work.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Javscript/pen/dymPJMP)